# Can't add parameters to getStaticProps for reloading a page with page 2, 3, 4, etc... of API fetched data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have this project here https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/custom-bp-one. It's just an experiment/learning experience for how to query GraphQL APIs via a Next.js app. I have a page that populates a table with Rick and Morty characters on page load. It looks like this:
[image]

And the code for the page looks like this:
characters.tsx

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import client from '../lib/apolloClient';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';


export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: gql`
        query getCharacters {
            characters(page: 1) {
                results {
                    id
                    name
                    species
                    status
                }
            }
        }`,
    });
    console.log(data);

    return {
      props: {
        characters: data.characters.results,
      },
   };
}

export default function Characters({ characters }: { characters: JSON[] }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <div>
                <div className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto">
                    <div>
                        Page #
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="overflow-x-auto relative shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">NAME</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">ROLE</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {characters?.map((section: any) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600" key={section.id}>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.name}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.species}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.status}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I want to add a page 2 button.  I changed the code to what I have below in an attempt to change the query parameter for `page` in the line `characters(page: 1)` and reload this next.js page on button presses.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import client from '../lib/apolloClient';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import Link from 'next/link';

interface DataObj {
    characters: {
        [results: string]: JSON;
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: { params: string }) {
    const preData = `{
        "data": {
            "characters": {
                "results": [
                    {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Rick Sanchez",
                    "species": "Human",
                    "status": "Alive"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }`;
    
    let data: DataObj = JSON.parse(preData);
      
    if (!params) {
        const { data } = await client.query({
            query: gql`
            query getCharacters {
                characters(page: 1) {
                    results {
                        id
                        name
                        species
                        status
                    }
                }
            }`,
        });
    } else {
        const { data } = await client.query({
            query: gql`
            query getCharacters {
                characters(page: ${params}) {
                    results {
                        id
                        name
                        species
                        status
                    }
                }
            }`,
        });
    }
    
    return {
      props: {
        characters: data.characters.results,
      },
   };
}

export default function Characters({ characters }: { characters: JSON[] }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <div>
                <div className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto">
                    <Link href="/characters/2">
                        <button type="button" className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-3 md:mr-0 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                            <span>
                                Page 2
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="overflow-x-auto relative shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">NAME</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">ROLE</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {characters?.map((section: any) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600" key={section.id}>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.name}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.species}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.status}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But it fails with this error:
[image]

So how do I get this to work? How do I add a parameter for a load page 2 functionality?

Also, I can't do anything with `getServerSideProps` because I want to build this as a static site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the characters page to a dynamic routing characters page. So the characters page used to be located at `pages/characters`, but now it's located at `pages/characters/[page].tsx`. [page].tsx's code looks like this:
page/characters/[page].tsx

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css'
import client from '../../lib/apolloClient';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { GetStaticPaths } from 'next';

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<{ page: string }> = async () => {

    return {
        paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
        fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: { params: any }) {
    let processedParam;

    if (!params || params?.page == null) {
        processedParam = 1;
    } else {
        processedParam = params.page
    }
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: gql`
        query getCharacters {
            characters(page: ${processedParam}) {
                results {
                    id
                    name
                    species
                    status
                }
            }
        }`,
    });
    return {
      props: {
        characters: data.characters.results,
      },
   };
}

export default function Characters({ characters }: { characters: JSON[] }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <div>
                <div className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto">
                    <Link href="/characters/2">
                        <button type="button" className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-3 md:mr-0 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
                            <span>
                                Page 2
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="overflow-x-auto relative shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">NAME</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">ROLE</th>
                            <th scope="col" className="py-3 px-6">STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {characters?.map((section: any) => {
                            return (
                                <tr className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600" key={section.id}>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.name}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.species}</td>
                                    <td className="py-4 px-6">{section.status}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```